# ADO .Net EDM in visual studio 2022 doesn't generate model classes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.8

I create a new wpf .net framework project. I connect ADO data models to it.
[image]

Select database objects to include
[image]

Database diagram is created fine
[image]

But data model classes are not defined
[image]

What could be the problem, I'm using Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6.1?

I tried reinstalling visual studio but that didn't help.

Comment: VS no longer supports FROM DATABASE option for Entity.  You must use Class First for your migration.

Comment: @jdweng  I've tried this on different computers in college, some work, some don't.

Comment: As liang hong chen said: change line 1920: to this:    _generationEnvironment = type.GetProperty("GenerationEnvironment");    Location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two solution:

(1).Turn your visual studio version back to 17.5.x.

(2)Open`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude`

change line 1920:

```
_generationEnvironment = type.GetProperty("GenerationEnvironment", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

to

```
_generationEnvironment = type.GetProperty("GenerationEnvironment");
```

this issue has been fixed in https://github.com/dotnet/ef6tools/commit/89cd126 by Adam Ratzman.

Comment: _generationEnvironment = type.GetProperty("GenerationEnvironment"); 

THIS REALLY HELPED, Thank you very much indeed!)